# Kivy UrlRequest with https

Tags: python-3.x, https, kivy, urlrequest

I'm trying to get Python 3.7 Kivy code to retrieve https web data using UrlRequest. Code works fine with http, but I get no data when I change the url to any https. When I compile and run with both http or https, both run without errors. Is there an import I need to add to make https work? This is test code. Thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from functools import partial

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
        button1 = Button(text="Press to say Hello", 
        on_release=self.run_Hello)
        button2 = Button(text="Kivy UrlRequest", 
        on_release=self.run_UrlRequests)
        blank_button = Button(text="Click me!")
        grid.add_widget(button1)
        grid.add_widget(button2)
        grid.add_widget(blank_button)
        return grid

def run_Hello(self, *args):
    print("Hello")


def run_UrlRequests(self, *args):
    for i in range(10):
        self.r = UrlRequest("https://www.google.com", verify=False, 
    on_success=partial(self.update_label, i), 
    on_error=partial(self.error_label, i))

def update_label(self, i, *args):
    print(i)
    print("success")
    print(self.r.result)

def error_label(self, i, *args):
    print("failed")
    print(i)
    print(self.r.result)
```

MainApp().run()

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def run_UrlRequests(self, *args):
    for i in range(10):
    self.r = UrlRequest("https://www.google.com", verify=False, 
    on_success=partial(self.update_label, i), on_error=partial(self.error_label, i))
```

I added verify=False after the UrlRequest, also to the original code. The code runs and generates a print statement of html data. Although this solves the https problem, I don't know if this apparent SSL issue has been addressed correctly.

Comment: I switched to Python3 from Python2 recently and ran into a similar error. The underlying problem for me was UrlRequest didn't know where the property CA file was. to solve it, I imported the certifi module `import certifi` and then passed `ca_file=certifi.where()`. A normal `requests.get` was working with https, but not Kivy's `UrlRequest`, not sure why exactly. Using `verify=False` is a bit of a security risk.

Comment: This solves the issue. Could not find documentation anywhere for it. Thank you!! BTW: Enjoy your Kivy videos.

Comment: I couldn't either, took me quite a while to figure out. Maybe I'll make a tutorial or post around it specifically haha! Thanks for your support!!