# How do I check whether Kivy UrlRequest Get is running on Android?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to scrape a website using Kivy's UrlRequest.  When I run the App from Android the code enters the `UrlRequest` function and never returns any information that it failed, an error occurred or success.
How can I "listen" for log ouput to find out why nothing happens?
Alternatively, what am I doing wrong with my UrlRequest code?

#### I have tried the following

1] Defined on_success, on_progress, on_error and on_failure functions to see if there is an output.

2] Created a settingspanel with different `chunk_size`, `debug`, `decode` and `timeout` values to see if it makes a difference when I change them.

3] Imported Kivy's `LoggerHistory` function to see if there is any error logs.

4] Looked at the `buildozer android logcat` output in the terminal to see what happens when I press the request button.

5] Changed url from `https://www.google.com` to `http://www.google.com`

6] Changed encoding from `'Latin-1'` to `'utf-16'` and back again.

7] Added a function using `Urllib.request` library to see if I can get anything and it gave me the following error:

```
07-30 21:51:09.933  9393  9417 I python  :  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)>
```

#### UrlRequest Code

```
    def req_url(self, *args):
        url_chnk = self.the.config.getint('urlreqsettings', 'optionschunk')
        tme = self.the.config.getint('urlreqsettings', 'inttime')
        dcode = self.the.config.getboolean('urlreqsettings', 'booldecode')
        dbug = self.the.config.getboolean('urlreqsettings', 'booldebug')
        self.ids.result_success.color = (0,0,1,1)
        self.ids.result_success.text = "Busy..."
        # self.ids.conn_status.text = str(url_chnk)
        the_request = UrlRequest(self.the._url,on_progress=self.on_progress, on_success=self.on_success, on_error=self.on_error, on_failure=self.on_failure, chunk_size=url_chnk, timeout=tme, debug=dbug, decode=dcode)
        self.ids.req_info.text = str(the_request.is_finished) + " - " + str(the_request.chunk_size)
    def on_success(self, the_request, result, *args):
        self.ids.req_info.text = str(the_request.is_finished) + " - " + str(the_request.chunk_size)
        # print(the_request.resp_headers)
        if self.prog_circle:
            self.loader.dismiss()
            self.ids.result_success.color = (0,0,1,1)
            self.ids.result_success.text = "Successful UrlRequest!"
            self.ids.get_result.text = ""
            self.ids.get_result.text = str(result, encoding='Latin-1')
            self.prog_circle = False
```

#### My Url that I use

```
config.setdefaults('myurl', {
            'url': 'https://www.google.com'})
```

#### Ouput Logcat when on_release button calling Kivy's UrlRequest function

```
07-30 21:44:42.795  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController: Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=true,activityOut=true,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:43:46,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
07-30 21:44:42.795  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController:    to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:43:46,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
07-30 21:44:42.861  1685  1748 E LightsService: Light requested not available on this device. 2
07-30 21:44:43.792  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 625 num clients 1
07-30 21:44:43.794  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=76508 Rx=110820
07-30 21:44:43.797  2122  2402 D MessengerImpl: <send> message = 1 ,msg.sendingUid = 1000 ,Handler = Handler (com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.WifiSignalController$WifiHandler) {3efccc8}
07-30 21:44:43.800  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController: Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:44:42,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
07-30 21:44:43.800  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController:    to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=false,activityOut=true,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:44:42,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
07-30 21:44:44.797  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 625 num clients 1
07-30 21:44:44.799  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=76509 Rx=110820
07-30 21:44:45.117   728   868 D SDM     : DisplayBase::BuildLayerStackStats: LayerStack layer_count: 7, app_layer_count: 6, gpu_target_index: 6, display type: 0
07-30 21:44:45.419   728   868 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) HwBinder:728_2 identical 1 line
07-30 21:44:45.637   728   868 D SDM     : DisplayBase::BuildLayerStackStats: LayerStack layer_count: 7, app_layer_count: 6, gpu_target_index: 6, display type: 0
07-30 21:44:45.800  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 625 num clients 1
07-30 21:44:45.802  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=76526 Rx=110835
07-30 21:44:45.803  2122  2402 D MessengerImpl: <send> message = 1 ,msg.sendingUid = 1000 ,Handler = Handler (com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.WifiSignalController$WifiHandler) {3efccc8}
07-30 21:44:45.805  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController: Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=false,activityOut=true,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:44:43,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
07-30 21:44:45.805  2122  2122 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController:    to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(Wi-Fi Icons),activityIn=true,activityOut=true,rssi=-51,lastModified=07-30 21:44:43,ssid="TP-Link_4837_5G",isTransient=false,statusLabel=null
```

#### Ouput Logcat when Urllib function button is released

```
07-30 21:51:09.902  9393  9417 I python  :  ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)
07-30 21:51:09.903  9393  9417 I python  :  
07-30 21:51:09.903  9393  9417 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
07-30 21:51:09.903  9393  9417 I python  :  
07-30 21:51:09.904  9393  9417 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-30 21:51:09.904  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 499, in <module>
07-30 21:51:09.905  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
07-30 21:51:09.906  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
07-30 21:51:09.906  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 746, in mainloop
07-30 21:51:09.907  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 478, in _mainloop
07-30 21:51:09.908  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
07-30 21:51:09.909  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
07-30 21:51:09.909  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
07-30 21:51:09.910  9393  9417 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-30 21:51:09.911  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
07-30 21:51:09.920  9393  9417 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
07-30 21:51:09.922  9393  9417 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
07-30 21:51:09.923  9393  9417 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
07-30 21:51:09.925  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/urlsign/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
07-30 21:51:09.926  9393  9417 I python  :    File "<string>", line 179, in <module>
07-30 21:51:09.926  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 300, in on_urllib_prog
07-30 21:51:09.927  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 303, in url_library
07-30 21:51:09.928  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
07-30 21:51:09.929  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
07-30 21:51:09.929  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
07-30 21:51:09.930  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
07-30 21:51:09.931  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
07-30 21:51:09.932  9393  9417 I python  :    File "/home/dataleaf/Build_Environ/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
07-30 21:51:09.933  9393  9417 I python  :  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)>
07-30 21:51:09.933  9393  9417 I python  : Python for android ended.
07-30 21:51:10.229  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 625 num clients 1
07-30 21:51:10.229  1685  1987 D WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=77858 Rx=112074
07-30 21:51:10.238  1685  1974 W InputDispatcher: channel '2fc1551 org.url_requesting.urlsign/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-30 21:51:10.238  1685  1974 E InputDispatcher: channel '2fc1551 org.url_requesting.urlsign/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-30 21:51:10.239  1685  4609 I ActivityManager: Process org.url_requesting.urlsign (pid 9393) has died: fore TOP 
07-30 21:51:10.240  1685  2993 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{2fc1551 u0 org.url_requesting.urlsign/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
07-30 21:51:10.240  1685  2993 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '2fc1551 org.url_requesting.urlsign/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)'
07-30 21:51:10.240   648   648 I Zygote  : Process 9393 exited cleanly (255)
07-30 21:51:10.241  1685  1750 W libprocessgroup: kill(-9393, 9) failed: No such process
07-30 21:51:10.241  1685  1750 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10272 pid 9393 in 0ms
07-30 21:51:10.243  1685  4609 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{e32495c u0 org.url_requesting.urlsign/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t6783}: app died, no saved state
```

#### Update

I removed the "s" from my url "https://orob.co.za" again, uninstalled the App completely from my phone and installed again (not updated).  This time the Urllib function gave the following error:

```
07-30 22:15:10.961 10706 10730 I python  :  socket.timeout: timed out
07-30 22:15:10.961 10706 10730 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

While the Kivy UrlRequest function for the first time entered the `on_progress` function.  But the request did not succeed, only times out.

#### Update on update and success albeit not HTTP... S!

Success! I cracked it.  When I had tried [5] above I had only updated the App on my phone and not uninstalled it.  I had also lost the plot and changed the domain to a different one than the one I used in the initial tests, which meant I got the right results but the wrong facts.  I have changed it back to "http://www.google.com" and the App returned the scrape ("Latin-1") for UrlRequest and Urllib. Very exiting!

The problem seems to be the SSL certificate.  I have openssl as part of my buidozer.spec file, so why is this not working in Android with HTTPS!

#### Update on update on update...

So my previous finding is correct.  Certificate verification is failing on the Kivy Urlrequest function for "HTTPS://..." url also.  After tweeking my code I found that the `on_error` function's `error` output is a `string` and not a byte-like object, that meant I tried `decoding` a string which caused the error and blocked the error output in my App:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)
```

#### Question edited

Can someone please help on how I can return the `result` from the scrape.. from url with https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have finally solved it and I am not sure of another way to inform others.
The SSL certificate question has many answers on this forum, but the information that solved my question are mostly comments.

#### Solution

Using Python 3.6.8 and Kivy 1.11.0

Step 1> I had to `pip3 install requests` to get the `certifi` python library.  
 See @Petar Luktina comments "[HTTPS Request in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482148/https-request-in-kivy)"

Step 2> Add the `ca_file=certifi.where()` parameter to your `UrlRequest()`.   As an extra I added the `verify=True` parameter.
 
See @Erik comments "[Kivy UrlRequest with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816099/kivy-urlrequest-with-https)"

Step 3> Add `certifi and openssl` to buildozer.spec file as Application requirements, else you would get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'`.  The error is due to an explicitly imported library that is not declared in the .spec file or does not form part of an already declared package

Step 4> Add functions to handle `on_success` parameter (not necessary but it worked for me).

My coded answer:

```
import certifi as cfi
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

    def req_url(self, *args):
        the_request = UrlRequest(self.the._url, on_success=self.on_success, 
                               on_error=self.on_error, on_failure=self.on_failure,
                                     ca_file=cfi.where(), verify=True)
```

Presto! It now works on Android.